# passing props from a mapped component to a component called into it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-functional-component

I admit that I am not very expert, and I need help with this
this is my "posts" component which is in charge of making an api call to get the data of all posts:

```
import React from 'react'
import Post from '../post/Post';
import "./posts.scss"
import { useQuery } from 'react-query'
import {makeRequest} from '../../axios'


const Posts = () => {
  
    const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery('posts', () =>
        makeRequest.get("/posts").then((res) =>{
          return res.data;
        })
      );
    


  return (
    <div className='posts'>
    {data?.map(post=>(
      <Post post={post} key={post.id}/>
    ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Posts
```

this component makes the "map" of the data it has received and passes the data to the "post" component which takes care of displaying the data for each single post received.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./post.scss";
import FavoriteBorderOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/FavoriteBorderOutlined";
import FavoriteOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/FavoriteOutlined";
import TextsmsOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/TextsmsOutlined";
import ShareOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ShareOutlined";
import MoreHorizIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MoreHoriz";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Comments from "../comments/Comments";
import moment from "moment";
import Updatepost from "../updatePost/Updatepost";

const Post = ({ post }) => {
  const [commentOpen, setCommentOpen] = useState(false);
  const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = useState(false);
  const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  const [openUpdate, setOpenUpdate] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="post">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="user">
          <div className="userInfo">
            <img src={post.profilePic} />
            <div className="details">
              <Link
                to={`/profile/${post.userId}`}
                style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "inherit" }}
              >
                <span className="name">{post.name}</span>{" "}
              </Link>
              <span className="date">{moment(post.createdAt).fromNow()}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <MoreHorizIcon onClick={() => setMenuOpen(!menuOpen)} />
          {menuOpen && (
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                setOpenUpdate(true);
                setMenuOpen(false);
              }}
            >
              Modifica
            </button>
          )}
        </div>
        <div className="content">
          <p>{post.desc}</p>
          <img src={"./upload/" + post.img} alt=""></img>
        </div>
        <div className="info">
          <div className="item " onClick={() => setIsLiked(!isLiked)}>
            {isLiked ? (
              <FavoriteOutlinedIcon />
            ) : (
              <FavoriteBorderOutlinedIcon />
            )}
            12 Mi piace
          </div>
          <div className="item" onClick={() => setCommentOpen(!commentOpen)}>
            <TextsmsOutlinedIcon />4 Commenti
          </div>
          <div className="item">
            <ShareOutlinedIcon />8 Condivisioni
          </div>
        </div>
        {commentOpen && <Comments />}
      </div>
      {openUpdate && (
        <Updatepost setOpenUpdate={setOpenUpdate} post={this.post} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

as you can see, i'm trying to pass the post data to the "UpdatePost" component to be able to do an update query later but when i try to do it saying
`<Updatepost setOpenUpdate={setOpenUpdate} post={post}` or `<Updatepost setOpenUpdate={setOpenUpdate } post={this.post}/>` tells me, doing the console log of the data on the Updatepost component that is undefined, someone can help e please?

As I said, I tried changing the "post" entry to this.post when passing props, but it didn't help. I need the data of the post I'm trying to modify in order to then perform the queries I need

Comment: it absolutely should not be `this.post` as this is a function component. just `post={post}` as you originally had should work - if `post` is undefined this component will already crash due to rendering things like `post.desc`. Can you share a runnable example of your code that demonstrates the problem, ideally in the question itself but failing that on a service like CodeSandbox?

Comment: Change to `post={post}` and show us the code for the `Updatepost` component. Also, share the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all for the very fast response, while I was preparing an example on code sandbox, I realized that the declaration of the parameters in Updatepost was done like this `{setOpenUpdate}, {post}` instead of `{setOpenUpdate, post}`